# Method in different class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int n;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
    n = s.nextInt();
    while(n!=69)
    {

    int a[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    int[]odds;
    OddsAndEvens s1 = new OddsAndEvens();
     odds = s1.getAllOdds();

    System.out.print("Odds- ");
    System.out.print( Arrays.toString(odds));
    System.out.println(" ");


    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Evens- ");

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
    n = s.nextInt();
    }
}
```

}

Secondary Class:

```
public class OddsAndEvens
```

{

```
private static int countEm(int[] a, int n,boolean odd,int count, int anticount)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] % 2 != 0)
        {

             count++;
        }

        anticount++;
    }
    return 0;
}

public static int[] getAllEvens(int[] a,int anticount,int n)
{
int[]gotevens = new int[anticount];
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        int toc = 0;
        if(a[i] % 2 == 0)
        {

            int a2 = a[i];
            gotevens[toc] = a2;
            toc++;
        }

    }

    return gotevens;

}

public static int[] getAllOdds(int[] a,int count,int n)
{
int[]gotodds = new int[count];
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        int tic = 0;
        if(a[i] % 2 != 0)
        {

            int a1 = a[i];
            gotodds[tic] = a1;
            tic++;
        }

    }

    return gotodds;
}
```

}

I keep getting the following error.

---

G:\MyProjects\Arraysoddsevens\OddsAndEvensRunner.java:33: error: method getAllOdds in class OddsAndEvens cannot be applied to given types;                               odds = s1.getAllOdds();
^
required:int[],int,int
found: no arguments                                                             reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length                     1 error

---

I've been googling for a solution with no luck.

Comment: This statement: `odds = s1.getAllOdds();` is not correct according to the way you declared `getAllOdds`, i.e. which expects 3 arguments.

Comment: There is a solution already, but you are also accessing a static method through an object, either access getAllOdds like "OddsAndEvens.getAllOdds(arr, count, n)", or remove the static modifier

Answer (score 0):

To call this method `getAllOdds()` you need 3 parameters see this:

```
 public static int[] getAllOdds(int[] a,int count,int n){...
```

Comment: How would I pass those parameters between classes?

Comment: @Nam3p3nding in Main class: try to add an array , an int count  and int n it's you can know these parameters.